# Updating a value inside an array state through toggling a Switch Component on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have a signUp component in React Native (without expo) that could have multiple email inputs, Each of them is followed by a Switch component that indicate if this is the main email or not. I'm using react useState, to manage the behavior of the list of fields. but when I press the switch to toggle the value of the main attribute, the Switch stuck and doesnt move until I execute the next operation (in this example, I've created a button that insert a new item on array and made another dummy working Switch). but if I print the value, it is toggling normally as expected, but the component itself doesnt respond immediately. Here is my code so far:

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {TextInput, View, Text, Switch, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function Signup() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([
    {
      email: '',
      main: true,
    },
  ]);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
  const setMainEmail = (value, emailIndex) => {
    const array = emails;
    console.log(array);
    array[emailIndex].main = value;
    console.log(array);
    setEmails(array);
  };
  const addNewEmail = () => {
    setEmails([
      ...emails,
      {
        email: '',
        principal: false,
      },
    ]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Text>Dummy Switch That Works</Text>
        <Switch
          trackColor={{false: '#767577', true: '#767577'}}
          thumbColor={isEnabled ? '#FD7E77' : '#f4f3f4'}
          ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
          onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
          value={isEnabled}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        {emails.map((email, emailIndex) => (
          <View key={emailIndex}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Email"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />
            <View>
              <Switch
                value={email.main}
                trackColor={{false: '#767577', true: '#767577'}}
                thumbColor={email.main ? '#FD7E77' : '#f4f3f4'}
                ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                onValueChange={event => setMainEmail(event, emailIndex)}
              />
              <Text color="#fff">Main?</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ))}
        <Button onPress={addNewEmail} title="+ Email" />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create a new array by spreading the previous array like this

```
const setMainEmail = (value, emailIndex) => {
    const array = [...emails];
    console.log(array);
    array[emailIndex].main = value;
    console.log(array);
    setEmails(array);
  };
```

This is the reason for the other scenario to work and this to fail, you are doing it right in the scenario where you add new items.